# App not working only on browserstack IOS devices

Tags: xamarin.forms, browserstack, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

Our cross platform app( build using Xamarin.Forms) is running successfully on all the physical devices and also on the Bowserstack Android devices, but it throws error on Browserstack IOS devices.

In the app, we are connecting with 3rd party i.e. Couchbase ( our backend) to sync the data using Couchbase lite nuget (https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net ) but seems like it is not syncing data for some reason only on Browserstack IOS devices which is causing the issue, and getting disconnected in-between.

Exception thrown by app:  "No response received after 15 sec -- disconnecting"

Kindly help, if anyone has any idea around this

I tried network throttling on Browserstack IOS devices in case if its network relate issue, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Kavita, any chance you have some code or test available to reproduce this issue so someone can look in details ?

Comment: "throws error" - is there a reason you haven't provided any detail about the error?

Comment: you can raise an issue with Browserstack at support@browserstack.com

Comment: @Jason Added error details in the original post

Comment: @LaurentDoguin Won't be possible to create sample app, as couchbase is paid library, and requires whole server setup. Cannot create dummy server and sync,  and can't use the actual server for security concerns.

Comment: @HomeLander I did, but update from their end so far